# Can the wadl file be generated at build time?

Tags: java, rest, ant, jersey, wadl

I am using Jersey. My wadl files are accessible once my code is deployed and my web server is up and running, but I would like to generate the wadl file at build time so  I can perform operations on it with other build targets. I see that the Jersey folks made a Maven plugin for this, but I am using Ant. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also an Ant util for this: [ant-wadl-task](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/tree/master/contribs/ant-wadl-task). Take a closer look to the test and [WadlGeneratorTask](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/blob/master/contribs/ant-wadl-task/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/api/wadl/WadlGeneratorTask.java#L82). Binary (1.18) can be downloaded [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/contribs/ant-wadl-task/1.18/ant-wadl-task-1.18.jar).

Comment: do know of any good examples or documentation on how to use ant-wadl-task ?

Comment: I don't know about documentation but example of use can be seen in the test (build.xml, ..).